# How to get a count of all children lists, grandchildren lists, great grandchildren lists etc. in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model, which has a list of objects, which has a list of objects, which has a list of objects and so on. What I am trying to do is get a count of all child objects, in a nice way.

I have set up the following example:

This is my model:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<GrandParent> GrandParents { get; set; }
}
```

And these are my objects:

```
public class GrandParent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the setup I have in a console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var friendOne = new Friend { Name = "Friend 1" };
        var childOne = new Child { Name = "Child 1", Friends = new List<Friend>() };
        var childTwo = new Child { Name = "Child 2", Friends = new List<Friend> { friendOne } };
        var parentOne = new Parent { Name = "Parent 1", Children = new List<Child> { childOne, childTwo } };
        var grandParentOne = new GrandParent { Name = "GrandParent 1", Parents = new List<Parent> { parentOne } };

        var model = new Model { GrandParents = new List<GrandParent> { grandParentOne } };

        var count = model.GrandParents.Count +
            model.GrandParents
                .Sum(gp => gp.Parents.Count + gp.Parents
                .Sum(p => p.Children.Count + p.Children
                .Sum(c => c.Friends.Count)));

        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So I have 5 objects (1 friend, 2 children, 1 parent and 1 grandparent), which my count variable is giving me. But I don't like the way I am doing it in my linq query, is there is a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Thus you have working code, it's a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it necessary to have distinct classes for `GrandParents`, `Parents` etc? If you could have only one type like `Person` with a `List<Person> Relatives` you could create a short recursive way. But maybe that's not what you regard as "better/cleaner".

Comment: @RenéVogt yes it is necessary to have distinct classes, this is just an example.

Comment: Ask Ben........ (EnumerateHierarchy)

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned in comments, one way is to use the same object for all nodes in your tree, and you could write something recursive.

Another way, if you want to keep these object would be to make them all implement an interface, which knows nothing more than how to count descendents.

```
public interface IHasDescendents
{
   int CountOfDescendents();
}
```

By implementing that interface for all classes, your code would simply be

```
var count = model.GrandParents.Sum(gp => 1 + gp.CountOfDescendents());
```

I suspect you could implement the details, but if not just comment and I'll show you how.

Comment: I'd rather not write a specific method for getting the count of the objects. This count that I need is actually required for a test assertion, so I wouldn't want to change implementation for my tests.

Comment: @Viqas huh? So you want a magic solution where you dont have to change anything. Ok. Good luck. BTW - you could explicitly implement the interface so it wasnt visible on the class itself, but the tests could cast to the interface for assertion.

Comment: @Viqas or, write a wrapper round your structure, used only for testing, which knows how to count descendants.